# how to resolve the error GET http://localhost:8484/ 401

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, cross-domain

I am coding a login page using angular, spring security and spring boot.
the problem is that i get the following error when i click on the login button:

[image: error in console]

[image: error in network]

however I did put crossorgine in my backend part as you can see here:

```
package com.app.habilitation.controller;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class UserController {


    @GetMapping("/")
    public String login() {
        return "authenticaated succesfully";
    }

    @GetMapping("/getUsers") 
    public String getUsers() {
        return "users";
    }
}
```

and here is my "usercontroller" controller which manages authentication:

```
package com.app.habilitation.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").
        fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("hr")
        .password("{noop}hr").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

and here is my routing in angular :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './components/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { InscriptionComponent } from './components/inscription/inscription.component';
import { HomeAdminComponent } from './components/home-admin/home-admin.component';


const routes: Routes = [

  {path:'', redirectTo:"login", pathMatch:"full"},
  {path: "forgot", component: ForgotPasswordComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'inscription', component: InscriptionComponent},
  {path:'home-admin', component: HomeAdminComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and this is my module :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './components/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { InscriptionComponent } from './components/inscription/inscription.component';
import { RestapiService } from './restapi.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HomeAdminComponent } from './components/home-admin/home-admin.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,
    InscriptionComponent,
    HomeAdminComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    MatCardModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [RestapiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and here is my service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestapiService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }


  public login(username:string, password:string) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({Authorization: 'Basic' + btoa(username+":"+password)})
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8484/", {headers, responseType:'text' as 'json'});
  }

  public getUsers() {
    let username="hr";
    let password="hr";
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({Authorization: 'Basic' + btoa(username+":"+password)});
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8484/getUsers", {headers});
  }
}
```

this is my login.ts page :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RestapiService } from 'src/app/restapi.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  username:string;
  password:string;
  message:any
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private service:RestapiService, private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  doLogin() {
    let resp = this.service.login(this.username, this.password);
    resp.subscribe(data=> {
      this.message =data;
      this.router.navigate(["home-admin"])
    })
  }
}
```

and this is my login.html page :

```
<div class="cnx">
  <!-- Default form login -->
  <form class="text-center border border-light p-5">

    <p class="h4 mb-4">Authentification</p>

    <!-- Email -->
    <input type="text" id="defaultLoginFormEmail" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Login" name="login" [(ngModel)]="username">

    <!-- Password -->
    <input type="password" id="defaultLoginFormPassword" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password">

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">

      <div>
        <!-- Forgot password -->
        <a routerLink="/forgot">Mot de passe oublié ?</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Sign in button -->
    <button mdbBtn color="info" block="true" class="my-4" type="submit" id="btn-authentification" (click)="doLogin()">Se connecter</button>

    <!-- Register -->
    <p>Tu n'es pas un membre ?
      <a routerLink= "/inscription">Enregistre toi</a>
    </p>


  </form>
  <!-- Default form login -->

</div>
```

(my spring boot server is running in port 8484 because I changed it in my application.properties file as you can see here):

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
spring.datasource.username=nawfel       
spring.datasource.password=hr


server.port=8484
```

can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a 401 Unauthorized error. It doesn't have anything to do with CORS. It seems you are missing a space after the `'Basic'` string literal. Try the following

```js
const headers = new HttpHeaders({Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password)})
```

Notice an empty space after `Basic`.

Comment: it works thank you very much !!! but I did not understand why we need a space after the "basic" ??

Comment: That is the format of the header according to standard. Please see the examples section here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Comment: Besides without the space, there wouldn't be a clear indication of the authentication type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Authentication_schemes

Comment: there is no implementation of cors in front end!

Comment: @AminSaadati: Strictly speaking the CORS should be handled by the back-end server. And it seems OP is sending the necessary response header.

Comment: @MichaelD yeah, and i meant front end should make some HTTP option  headers and also as u say the back should implement cors system. start origin a little does not make any sense